# I want to enable the a particular column of my dataGrid to edit on button click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, command-pattern

I want to disable(close for editing) the 3rd column of my dataGrid(using MVVM-WPF) but want to enable to edit again on click of button outside the Grid.How can I achieve that? 
The Challenge  I am facing here is how to retrieve dataGrid's property on button click, I am using command pattern out here .This is how my ViewModel looks now, what I am supposed to write in those method to make certain column editable:

```
   public class TicketOverViewViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private TicketDataService ticketDataService;

        private ObservableCollection<Ticket> tickets;

        public ObservableCollection<Ticket> Tickets
        {
            get
            {
                return tickets;
            }
            set
            {
                tickets = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Tickets");
            }
        }

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public TicketOverViewViewModel()
        {
            ticketDataService = new TicketDataService();
            LoadData();
            LoadCommands();


        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            tickets = ticketDataService.GetAllTickets().ToObservableCollection();
        }



        public ICommand EditCommand { get; set; }
        private void LoadCommands()
        {
            EditCommand = new CustomCommand(EditTicket, CanEditTicket);
        }


        private void EditTicket(object obj)
        {
            //TODO
        }

        private bool CanEditTicket(object obj)
        {

            return true;

        }
    }
```

This is how my Customcommand looks:

```
public class CustomCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Predicate<object> canExecute;

        public CustomCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            bool b = canExecute == null ? true : canExecute(parameter);
            return b;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            execute(parameter);
        }
    }
```

My View:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridMVVM.View.TicketOverView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridMVVM.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Ticket Overview" Height="348.936" Width="421.277"
        DataContext= "{Binding Source={StaticResource mainViewModelLocator},  Path=TicketOverViewViewModel }">
    <Grid>

        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding Tickets}" IsReadOnly="True"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="True" Height="100" Width="400" />
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Edit" Command="{Binding EditCommand}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="239,183,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Since my grid is read only when view is loaded I want to make it editable on edit button click by using command pattern rather than doing in codebehind (View's code behind)page.

Answer (score 0):

Swap around the read only attributes on each cell.  So start like this

```
dataGridView1.Rows[row.index].Cells[column.index].ReadOnly= true;
```

then on button click

```
dataGridView1.Rows[row.index].Cells[column.index].ReadOnly= false;
```

you can set the whole row or column like this

```
dataGridView1.Rows[row.index].ReadOnly= false;
dataGridView1.Columns[columns.index].ReadOnly= false;
```

or the entire grid

```
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
```

Comment: @ Chanchal,  I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: Here is the problem:I have a grid with a column having some data and that can be edited  after user clicks on Edit button below the grid. The requirement is to keep the cells in the grid non-editable until the Edit button is clicked. The entire grid cannot be disabled as Scroll bar should be enabled to scroll through the rows.

Comment: @ Chanchal  I am suggesting you set the grid to ReadOnly.  This is different than Enabled.  ReadOnly keeps things enabled but prevents the user from editing the text.  Scrollbars will still work.